# How can I make a carob coating?

Tags: baking, cookies, carob

I want to make Italian Three color Christmas Cookies (like these: http://www.food.com/recipe/italian-tri-color-cookies-rainbow-cookies-147882 ). This kind of cookie is traditionally are covered in melted chocolate, but my husband and son are both allergic to chocolate. The last time I tried to melt carob chips, I discovered that carob doesn't melt (it was awful...). So... how can I make a carob coating for these cookies?

Comment: Carob chips should melt just fine. Can you elaborate on what you tried and what happened? (Sorry if it's a painful memory, but it might help you get better answers)

Comment: I've tried it more than once, melting over a double boiler, and each time, the carob clumped, solidified, and made what my husband called very good toffee. It was odd, to say the least. Nothing like the smooth melt I get with chocolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melting carob is a bit different from chocolate.  The sugar crystal formation is not the same for tempering chocolate.  One suggestion is to add paramount crystals (which is a combination of palm kernel oil and soy lecithin) to help start/control the process.  I would also recommend not keeping the double boiler actually on the double boiler for the entire time.

Heat it up until some of the carob melts.  Remove from heat and stir.  Add it back to the heat and continue removing to stir as each bit melts a little more.  It takes longer but it allows you to control the heating and crystallization process.

End the end, you should have a smoother and more even end result.

Comment: Where would I find paramount crystals???

Comment: Most baking, cooking, or health food type stores will have them. I think I even saw some in the craft stores like Michael's or JoAnn Fabric that have candy making stuff.  Of you can order online.  They are made up of palm kernel oil and soy lecithin.

Comment: I will have to try and find these! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

double boiler not necessary if you have a microwave, just work on 10 second rotations (micro, stir, micro, stir, etc.)

Comment: If the OP is having trouble even with a double boiler, this sounds even less likely to work.